# Modifying a component defined in TestBed.overrideComponent

Tags: angular, typescript, integration-testing, specifications, testbed

We are using

```
TestBed.overrideComponent(CoolComponent, {
    set: {
      template: '<div id="fake-component">i am the fake component</div>',
      selector: 'our-cool-component',
      inputs: [ 'model' ]
    }
  })
```

to override a component.

The component has a ViewChild which we configure in our ngOnInit method

```
@Component({
  selector: 'our-cool-component',
  templateUrl: 'cool.component.html'
})
export class CoolComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() model: SomeModel
  @ViewChild(CoolChildComponent) coolChildComponent;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.coolChildComponent.doStuff();
  }
}
```

The `CoolComponent` in turn lives in a `Wrapper` component.

When we call `fixture.detectChanges()` on the `Wrapper` fixture, this attempts to construct the CoolComponent, but it immediately dies when it calls doStuff() because `CoolChildComponent` is undefined.

Is there a way to get at the `CoolComponent` to stub its `CoolChildComponent`? It doesn't seem like we can get it off the `Wrapper` because it's only referenced through the template, not as a property of the component.

Comment: I just added a bounty, apparently you aren't informed (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333838/3001761)

Comment: Has this ever been working? Does it work when you're running it in the browser (or whatever you're targeting)? Is this a testing only problem?

Answer (score 8):

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.coolChildComponent.doStuff();
}
```

should be

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.coolChildComponent.doStuff();
}
```

[because](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-var.html)

> View child is set before the ngAfterViewInit callback is called.

Comment: Nope, this does not make a difference for me.